# Is "War needs heroes" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, slogan

It's intended to be used as a slogan of a war-type game. Should the subject be "war" or "a war" or "wars"? And what the verb form should be accordingly?

Comment: Why not? Simple "subject - indicative verb - object". No different to *Horses need hay*.

Comment: Any of the three would be correct: which is best in context is a matter for the writer to decide.

Comment: When General Sherman said "War is hell", no one argued with him.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration that war may act as noun, verb or an adjective (ex.war preparations) in a sentence, I guess it would be alright to use war needs heroes.

As an abstract noun, war, as an event, needs a singular verb to follow grammar rules.